# Redundant string initialization warning when using initializer list in the default constructor

Tags: c++

```
class person
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int hungerLevel;
    std::string location;
    int money;
public:
    person() : name(""), hungerLevel(100), location(""), money(0) {}
};
```

When I initialize my string variables as empty strings in the default constructor using the Initializer list I get the warning "Redundant string initialization".

```
class person
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int hungerLevel;
    std::string location;
    int money;
public:
    person() : hungerLevel(100), money(0)
    {
        name = "";
        location = "";
    }
};
```

However, when I initialize my strings as empty strings in the body of the constructor as demonstrated above I don't get any errors. I'm not sure if this warning is only related to IDE that I'm using or if one of them is the proper way/good practice.

Comment: In the 2nd snippet you're **assigning** while in the 1st snippet your are **initializing** which is redundant as the warning says in first case. There is no need to initialize the string like `name("")`, when you can just write `name()`.

Comment: That's because the strings are not initialized "in the body of the constructor". They have already been initialized. The body of the constructor assigns to them. Assignment is not the same thing as initialization. But, it's a bogus warning, nevertheless.

Comment: *When I initialize my string variables as empty strings* -- By default, `std::string` is empty.  The code, regardless of the warning, is redundant.

Comment: I see, so what would be the proper way to assign/initialize those strings as empty strings ```name()``` in the initializer list or assigning as empty strings in the body of the function. Or both of them would be considered bad or unecessary

Comment: @nyms1 Don't do anything.  A `std::string`'s default constructor makes the string empty.  `person() : hungerLevel(100), money(0) {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gist of your question has been answered in the comments, but you can avoid a constructor altogether here by declaring your class like this:

```
class person
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int hungerLevel = 100;
    std::string location;
    int money = 0;
};
```

This (to me) has the huge advantage that you have the declaration and initialisation of all your member variables in the same place and avoids the danger of forgetting to initialise one in your constructor's initialiser list (which can happen if you add a new member variable, typically).  It also means that those variables will be initialised correctly even if you add another constructor, it's a win-win situation.

As others have said, the compiler will emit code to intialise your `std::string`s automatically (by calling the default constructor), so that will take care of itself.

Comment: Asked this style of coding to our professor earlier (Instantiating members in the declaration). He encouraged us to use the default constructor for anything regarding the default constructor. (I have no idea why, I'm still very new to c++), would you consider this style of coding better than using a default constructor in this case?

Comment: Yes, for the reasons stated.    You should ask your professor why he is telling you different.  And you're initialising them, not instantiating them (that happens when the object comes into existence).

Comment: One possible reason to avoid the `int money = 0;` style of initialization is if you want your code to compile under pre-C++11 C++ compilers; that feature was introduced in C++11.  Whether that's important to you to will depend on what compilers your program needs to support.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413154/c-initializing-variables-in-header-vs-with-constructor

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I really, really hope that doesn't apply to the OP.

Comment: I see thank you all for the answers helped out alot!

Comment: @PaulSanders quite a number of post-C++11 partially-compliant AND popular compilers still didn't support that particular feature for long time. I was stuck with one until this year. Another reason to avoid it that is a code style consideration. On surface the class may look trivial, but it isn't. Easy to make mistake.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie OK, but it wouldn't be trivial if it had the OP's original constructor either, would it?

Comment: @PaulSanders it would be *obviously* non-trivial, that's what I mean. In high stress situation `int money = 0;` may get overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

An assignment isn't initialization, there is a limit what static analyzer can detect (although some advanced ones would nag at you in either case). `std::string` isn't a trivially-constructed class, so its constructor would be called anyway, so both are redundant.

Another reason to keep initialization list (while using Paul Sander's suggestion) is for code  re-use in following form:

```
class person
{
    std::string name;
    int hungerLevel = 100;
    std::string location;
    int money = 0;
public:
    person(std::string birthName, std::string home) 
    : name(birthName), location(home) { 
         registerNewPerson(); 
    } 

    person() 
    : person("John Doe", defaultLocation()) { 
         reportJD();
    }
};
```

`hungerLevel` and `money` would always have same intialization, and `person(string, string)` is a constructor which can be reused in other scenarios.