# what is the differnce between these two method of Dynamic allocation of array in a class

Tags: c++

I am trying to dynamically allocate a array inside a class. Came across a very weird thing. Please have look on this two piece of code and do tell me the difference.

```
class A{

public:
    int n;

    int *a;

    a = new int [4];

    ~A(){delete []a;}

    A(){}
}
```

Compiling with GCC produces the following error:

> a does not a name type

But when I use:

```
class A{

public:

    int n;

    int *a = new int [4];

    A(){}
    ~A(){ delete []a;}
}
```

It compiles

Answer (score 4):

```
a= new int [4];
```

Is not an initialization but an assignment and is not allowed.

```
int *a = new int [4];
```

Works as it is an [in class initilization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662441/c11-allows-in-class-initialization-of-non-static-and-non-const-members-what-c) and is allowed in C++11 and beyond.

You are also mixing `new[]` and `delete`.  Whenever you use `new` you should have a call to `delete` and when you use `new[]` you need to call `delete[]`

Now instead of dealing with pointers and `new[]` and `delete[]` you should use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Please be an angel an say you **must** use `delete[]`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an initialization:

```
int *a = new int [4];
```

This is an assignment which can't be done in a class declaration, but can be done, e.g., in a constructor:

```
a = new int [4];
```

Also, if you use `new[]`, you also need to use `delete[]`, not `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear on what exactly you're shooting for, but this work should be done in the constructor and destructor of the class

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { a = new int[4]; }
    ~A() { delete[] a; }
private:
    int* a;
};
```

and better yet, you could avoid doing any dynamic allocation yourself if you use `std::vector`

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : a(4) {}
private:
    std::vector<int> a;
};
```

Comment: Plus one, you've fixed the undefined behaviour encountered when using `delete`.

Comment: Thnask Kramer .. i do not have specific target..just a query.. ..was just playing with ,,i use vectors a lot..