# Please clarify const qualifier propagation

Tags: c++

Suppose we have a following piece of code:

```
class Base {
  public:
    int a = 5;
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    Base *parent_ = new Base;
    Base* parent() const { return parent_; }
};

void f(const Derived *derived) {
    Base *p = derived->parent();
    p->a = 10; // <- is this correct?
}
```

Personally I think here is a problem:

> In function `f` we take a pointer to `const` object of class `Derived`. This makes each member of it also `const` thus `parent_` becomes `const Base *`. If it is const we should not have an ability to modify the object on which the pointer points.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: `int a = 5;` - is this C++11?

Comment: `parent_` is of type `Base * const`, not `const Base *`.

Comment: @sashoalm yes, it is. But I did not tag the question with `c++11` because it is irrelevant.

Comment: @sashoalm [yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662441/c11-allows-in-class-initialization-of-non-static-and-non-const-members-what-c).

Comment: @VictorPolevoy the [c++] tag designates the latest standard, that is C++14 for now. So that's fine.

Comment: @Quentin well, nice, thanks, did not know that. Well, people still want to add these tags which does not makes the question any better :/ Lol, here is a war, one makes an edit with tags `c++11` and `c++14`, other deletes them both, funny to see :)

Comment: btw the question is not really specific to inheritance. Imho it would be better edit and remove any inheritance stuff

Comment: @tobi303 I am not best at looking for the words to say but is not that some kind of synonym of "inheritance"?

Comment: well there is inheritance in your code, but the problem is not caused by that. The answers dont even mention inheritance. Imho better title would be "Clarify const qualifier when returning pointer"

Comment: @VictorPolevoy : tobi303 was referring to `Derived` inheriting from `Base` in your code sample - that has no impact on your question, and in fact can cause some confusion with the use of `Base` as both a base class and a member.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy the usual term for this mechanism is *const propagation*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This makes each member of it also const thus `parent_` becomes `const Base *`.

No, the pointer will become const itself, not the object it points to. So `parent_` becomes `Base * const`, not `const Base *`, and your code is valid.

Answer (score 5):

```
Base* parent() const { return parent_; }
```

Unfortunately, this is problem with C++. Method is `const`, but it is returning a non-const pointer, which would allow following operation to succeed:

```
p->a = 10; // <- is this correct?
```

It is programmer's responsibility not to return non-const pointer or references from functions (method being const or not).

Comment: According to @songyuanyao 's answer this is not a problem since we change the object which remains `non-const` because the only thing that becomes `const` by `const propagation` is the pointer itself.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I'd say it is a problem. You're not breaking the language, but you're breaking logical constness.

Answer (score 0):

As **tobi303** points out below, this answer is **wrong**. Keeping it here for the sake of the discussion below.

---

I could be wrong, but this line:

```
    Base* parent() const { return parent_; }
```

does not mention anything about returning const objects. It is equivalent to

```
    Base* parent() const { return this->parent_; }
```

where `this` is `const Derived*`, but `parent_` is still `Base*`.

Comment: the member of a `const` object is also `const`, otherwise the whole `const` story would be useless for public members

Comment: @tobi303 you seem to not understand the difference between `const T *` and `T * const`

Comment: `this` is `const Derived* const`, `parent_` is `Base* const`.

Comment: @M.M i do understand the difference. but as   songyuanyao pointed out, if `this` is `const` then also its member `parent_` is `const`.  As the member is a pointer, as a member of a `const` object it becomes a `const` pointer (pointing to a non-const object). Actually it wasnt my intention to call this answer "wrong"....

Comment: @tobi303, I am actually thankful that you corrected me. Maybe a concise version of the current discussion should be edited into the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

A const method only prevents the method from modifying any non-mutable data members of the class.

If you want to not allow the modification of `a` and don't want to update the class, you need to write:

```
const Base *p = derived->parent();
```

However, I would recommend you to not return non-const data members from a class as ref or pointer because this breaks the data encapsulation concept of C++. This is the same, of course, with the public `a`.