# C++ Class Contructor setting Variables whats the difference between those tho ways?

Tags: c++, constructor, operators

first here is the example Code:

**cPerson.h:**

```
#pragma once
class cPerson
{
public:
    cPerson();
    ~cPerson();
    int Age;
};
```

**cPerson.cpp**

```
#include "cPerson.h"

cPerson::cPerson()
{
    this->Age = 3; // Way 1
    cPerson::Age = 4; // Way 2
}

cPerson::~cPerson() { }
```

**Ok now my Question:**

If we are defining a new Class in C++ there are two ways to set the initial Values. There is (Way 1) by using the "this"-pointer, or (Way 2) using the scope operator ( :: ).
In school I learned it using "this->". Now, years after not using C++, I startet to get into it again and found this second way, using the scope operator.
Both way work fine BUT what's the exact difference between them and what's the "faster"/"better" way? I'm that kind of guy who likes to know what exactly is going on in my ram/cpu if I'm programming.

So I hope someone can help me out, and thanks in advance.

Comment: You could simply write `Age = 3;` or better use a member initializer list as mentioned by Bathsheba. Most of the time, you should not qualify a member of your class, so you should be using `Age` directly instead of `this->Age` or `cPerson::Age`.

Comment: In your particular example, there is no difference.  Typically, the compiler will handle them both the same way.   There are other ways too.

Comment: Prefixing a class name with `c` isn't the best idea

Comment: @PasserBy: Why?

Comment: It is redundant information, and gets in the way. The reader will be able to see that a name is a type when they see the surrounding context. You are _not_ going to mistake `Person jonskeet;` as something else

Comment: @Passer By: oh ok yea thats not my usual style neither. But I was hoping for an more interresting answet to this question :D I don't know what I expected.

Comment: @Peter: your answer was the most interresting one thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to write the constructor as

```
cPerson::cPerson() : Age(3)
{
}
```

since then you can construct a `const` instance of your object. Consider starting `Age` with a lower case letter: this would be more conventional.

You could refine your first way by writing the more succinct `Age = 3;`: sometimes initialising members in the constructor body is unavoidable if they depend on the result of complex calculations.

Using `::` is idiosyncratic: using the scope resolution operator will fail if the member is defined in a base class. But it does have occasional usage, particularly if you need to disambiguate a *shadowed* base class member.

Finally, from C++11 onwards you could simplify your class to

```
struct cPerson
{
    int Age = 3;
};
```

See [C++11 allows in-class initialization of non-static and non-const members. What changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662441/c11-allows-in-class-initialization-of-non-static-and-non-const-members-what-c)

Comment: Nice tanks for the answer. I was expecting C++11 was involved in some way. I just couldn't find any information. Your link was a good information source, tanks. And yea simplifying would be a good thing in this case. Althoug it's just ment to be an example.