# C++ HashTable, two same implementations but one gives an error

Tags: c++, static, hashtable

Code below produces this error:

```
class HASHTABLE
{
public:
  const int DIMENSION = 10;
  struct NODE
  {
     char* INFO;
     NODE* LINK;
  };
  NODE arr1[DIMENSION];
};


int main()
{
  const int dimension=10;
  struct node
  {
    char* info;
    node* link;
  };
  node arr2[dimension];
};
```

So, code in `int main()` gives no errors, but code in `class HASHTABLE` when i declare  `NODE arr1[DIMENSION];`  I get error: `int(10) a nonstatic member reference must be relative to specific object.`

The solution is obvious, just put `static const int DIMENSION = 10;` and I get no errors.

But for how much I understand C++, this code in `main` and in  `class` are the same.

Can someone explain what happens behind the scene?

Also, I hope I understand this:

If I declare `DIMENSION` as a static, every object I create using `HASHTABLE` will have also the same `DIMENSION`, but I thought that was secured via using `const`?

Answer (score 1):

> But for how much i understand c++, this code in main and in  class are same.

they are different. for class case, if you don't add `static`, every instance of HASHTABLE has it's own DIMENSION.

I found `const static` is required if you want to do this inside `class`.
I guess the compile error is because of the compiler can't determine the value of DIMENSION if DIMENSION is not declared as `static`.

> i tought that was secured via using const

`const` is to prevent the variable from being written. But `static` in class is to declare a shared variable between instances.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. But i just dont understand why it needed to be `static`? It was already const, so every instance of HASHTABLE would have its DIMENSION=10. I realy think word `static` is unnecessary, or im missing something?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662441/c11-allows-in-class-initialization-of-non-static-and-non-const-members-what-c) shows some restrictions of class member initialization. probably it's the cause.